# What is the format to call accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

In my *iOS table view* I have a function required by the `TableViewDelegate`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        savedRow = indexPath.row
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SubcategorySegue", sender: self)
}
```

I first get the `indexPath` by executing the following:

```
@IBAction func showSubcategoryEditor(sender: UIButton) {
    let switchFrameOrigin = sender.frame.origin
    if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(switchFrameOrigin) {
        tableView.delegate.accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath!(indexPath)
    }
}
```

This results in an error indicating that delegate is not recognized.
Should I use: `tableView.accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath(indexPath)`?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using the showSubcategoryEditor method. What button is that for? What does that have to do with the accessory button, and why would you want to call the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method anyway. It's called when you tap on the accessory button.

Comment: It is a a table view controller which segues to another table view controller. The first allows selection of a category. The second allows selection of sub-categories corresponding to the category. I could have implemented it with a built in accessory button but I wanted to use a custom button instead. I needed to learn how I could use the custom button as an accessory button.which would call the method "accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath". My function "ShowSubcategoryEditor" uses the sender.frame.origin to locate the row in which the pressed button is located. Then call accessoryButton.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to substitute a custom button (strictly for aesthetics) and have it behave as a system-provided accessory. Unfortunately, I have not succeeded so far. Fortunately, I can use the standard accessory button until I figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the system provided accessory button, and you tap on the button, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath is called for you by the system, and the system passes in the correct indexPath. When you call the method yourself, you have to pass in the indexPath, which you are getting from indexPathForRowAtPoint (but you need to convert the point to the table view's coordinate system like I show in the code below). So, since you already have the indexPath in your button's action method, there's no need to call accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath, it's just an extra step that doesn't do any more than what you can do in the button's action method. You only need to do this,

```
@IBAction func showSubcategoryEditor(sender: UIButton) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint) {
        savedRow = indexPath.row
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SubcategorySegue", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Notice also, that in performSegue:sender:, I am passing the indexPath as the sender argument. You can then use that in prepareForSegue:sender: to get the row if you need to pass information to your destination view controller.

If you connect the segue from your button to the next controller, then there's no need to even have a button action method; everything can be done in prepareForSegue:sender:. The sender argument will be the button, so you can do this,

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let button = sender as UIButton
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController // substitute the class of your destination view controller
        let hitPoint = button.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint) {
            // pass the index path to controller, or get data from your array based on the indexPath, and send that to controller
        }
    }
```

Comment: rdelmar - Thank you for the very well designed answer. Works great! I have already incorporated your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was provided on the Apple Forum:

> Within the `UITableViewController` subclass, which implements the
>   delegate protocol, you can call the delegate method like this:

```
tableView(tableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:
indexPath)
```

Comment: Why bother to call accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath at all if you already have a button method? Just call performSegue in showSubcategoryEditor; it's an extra step that's unnecessary. Even easier, connect the button to a segue in the storyboard, then you don't need either method.

Comment: I need the number of the row that was selected to show the right data in the subcategory table. The subcategory table is not static. Each category has a different set of subcategories.

Comment: You have the indexPath in your button method. If you don't implement either method, then you should implement prepareForSegue, and you can get the indexPath there the same way you do in your button method (the button will be the sender argument o  prepareForSegue:sender:).

Comment: Help me understand your suggestion. I need to know the row in which the button was pressed. The button irrespective of the row always calls the special button method which sends the sender as an argument. A button method does not get me the row info directly. For example, if I choose to use the system-provided accessory buttons (detail, detail disclosure) I don't have a problem because touching the system-provided accessory executes accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath from which I can determine the indexPath.row. (Continued)

Comment: Unfortunately if I do so the compiler finds the tableView variable in the UITableViewController class and of course reports it may not be treated as a function.